# The image draws itself again

Tags: c#, image-processing

So I am working on a project, and I am currently on the finishing touches in the Image Part. But here comes the problem. When I clicked the checkbox for **flipping the image**, it flips.

Like this:
[image]

But when I click the "Accept" Button (this is for saving the image into a collection of objects), this happens:

[image]

I used Visual Studio's debugger and what I think the problem is that, the onPaint of the pictureBox is being called numerous time again so is the method for Image Drawing. So my question is, how do I prevent that from happening?

**Image Drawing Method**

```
public LayerClass ImageDrawing(LayerClass.Type img, Bitmap bm, RectangleF imgRect, String filepath, int angle, PaintEventArgs e, PointF location, bool flip)
    {
        bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(filepath);
        bm = new Bitmap(bm, (int)imgRect.Width, (int)imgRect.Height);  //Scaling Image
        bm = ImageClass.GrayscaleImage(bm);             //Grayscale
        bm = MakeTransparentImage(bm);                //Transparent
        bm = RotateImage(bm, angle);
        if (flip)
            bm.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
        imgRect.Size = new SizeF(bm.Width, bm.Height);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, imgRect.X - (bm.Width / 2), imgRect.Y - (bm.Height / 2));
        this.imageBitmap = bm;
        this.filePath = filePath;
        this.rotationAngle = angle;
        this.location = location;
        this.imageRect = imgRect;
        this.flipped = flip;
        return new LayerClass(LayerClass.Type.Image, this, filePath, imgRect, location, flip);
    }
```

Comment: Just FYI, your code is full of GDI unmanaged resource leaks, dispose your images and GDI resources. However your problem is because you are calling    `e.Graphics.DrawImage` over the original image

Comment: So where should I put the e.Graphics.DrawImage?

Comment: is the "ths.imageBitmap = bm" the original image you're pertaining to?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that you draw your image on your canvas, but you are not erasing the previously drawn image.

Think about it like this: If you draw something on a piece of paper and then want to draw something new, but you don't use a fresh piece, you end up with your old drawing beneath your new one.

Your code works just like this right now.

So instead, before you draw your flipped image, you first have to erase your old image.

The easiest way to do this is to call

```
e.Graphics.Clear(this.Background); //Use any color you want.
```

before you call

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage
```